# Native infinite range?

Tags: python

Does python have a native iterable of the infinite integer series?

I've tried `range(float('inf'))` and `iter(int)`, but neither work.

I can obviously implement my own generator along the lines of

```
def int_series(next=1):
    while True:
        next += 1
        yield next
```

but this feels like something which should already exist.

Comment: In what practical purposes would you need an `inf`

Comment: How is this "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. It's absurd to vote to close such a coherent question.

Comment: @sshashank124 In Haskell we use infinite lists all the time. Of course it's not strictly *necessary*, but it allows for some elegant solutions

Comment: @sshashank124 Or are you asking when the float value `infinity` is useful? Everytime you need an `R` such that `abs(x) < R` for all finite `x`. For example it is the neutral element of the minimum monoid

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes. It's [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.count()
>>> next(x)
0
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> # And so on...
```

You can specify `start` and `step` arguments, though `stop` isn't an option (that's what `xrange` is for):

```
>>> x = itertools.count(3, 5)
>>> next(x)
3
>>> next(x)
8
>>> next(x)
13
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for this.

```
for x in itertools.count():
    # do something with x infinite times
```

If you don't want to use the integer returned by `count()`, then better use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
for _ in itertools.repeat(None):
     # do something infinite times
```

Comment: If you don't want the integer, `while True` is much more appropriate.

Comment: @user2357112 While loop can be twice as slow compared to a for-loop.

Comment: If that tiny overhead really matters, `while 1` is compiled to an unconditional jump, which is even faster than the for loop. Most likely, the time taken by the loop body will dominate and the difference won't matter.

Comment: Overhead is irrelevant for a loop that’s going to run an infinite number of times ;-)

Comment: @user2357112 In python3.3 `while True` compiles to **exactly** the same instructions as `while 1` (i.e. `SETUP_LOOP` + `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`). In python2.7 there is a difference. I don't have previous versions of python3 to check, but I believe already in python3.0 they were equivalent.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Because `for` doesn't check any conditions, it just waits for the iterator supplied to it to throw a `StopIteration` exception, right? I could see that posing a problem if the `while` condition were complicated, but terminating generators/iterators have their own termination logic internally anyway so I'm not sure it makes much of a difference for the vast majority of cases unless the internal logic is also exception-driven.